# How to get only yyyy-mm-dd and ignore all the rest

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, mongoose

I want to save to db date as Date type so I got data like this in my db

```
2022-05-04T23:00:00.000+00:00
```

i want to save just

```
2022-05-04
```

Comment: `.split('T')[0]`

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73229100/how-to-get-only-yyyy-mm-dd-and-ignore-all-the-rest#comment129328835_73229100) @JaromandaX No need for the intermediate array only to pick the first element: `dateString.slice(0, 10)`

Comment: You do you @jsejcksn  either way we both wrote more code than the OP

Comment: I want data saved as Date type not string

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, MongoDB Date data type always has the time part. It is not like many SQL databases which offer e.g. Date and DateTime data types.

A common workaround is to store the date instead as a `number` data type, with format "YYYYMMDD".

With this, we can still easily query with comparison operators.

It is not uncommon that people also do this trick for SQL databases, even when a Date-only data type could have been used.